# How to set value in dynamically built drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of menus that should be built and populated dynamically. While creating these elements I should populate the value in each drop down menu. Here is example:

```js
var ajax_data = [{
    section_1: "Y",
    section_2: "Y",
    section_3: "N"
  },
  {
    section_1: "Y",
    section_2: "Y",
    section_3: "N"
  },
  {
    section_1: "Y",
    section_2: "Y",
    section_3: "Y"
  },
  {
    section_1: "N",
    section_2: "",
    section_3: "N"
  }
];

$('#btn-show').on('click', function() {
  let $tbl_body = $('#tbl-info > tbody');
  $tbl_body.html('');

  for (key in ajax_data) {
    let $tbl_row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $tbl_row.append($('<td><select class="custom-select" name="section1_' + key + '" id="section1_' + key + '"><option value="">-Select-</option><option value="Y">Enabled</option><option value="N">Disabled</option></select></td>'));
    $tbl_row.append($('<td><select class="custom-select" name="section2_' + key + '" id="section2_' + key + '"><option value="">-Select-</option><option value="Y">Enabled</option><option value="N">Disabled</option></select></td>'));
    $tbl_row.append($('<td><select class="custom-select" name="section2_' + key + '" id="section3_' + key + '"><option value="">-Select-</option><option value="Y">Enabled</option><option value="N">Disabled</option></select></td>'));
    $tbl_body.append($tbl_row);
  }
  $('#info_modal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-show">Show Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="info_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Data Information</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table id="tbl-info" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr class="bg-custom">
                <th>Section 1</th>
                <th>Section 2</th>
                <th>Section 3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone have idea on how to populate values in drop down menus please let me know.

Comment: Just append `<option>` in whichever `<select>` you want, what's so challenging? If you are concerned about messy code yes I agree in that case I'd suggest https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

Comment: @Viney Can you provide example on how to set the value for each drop-down elements?

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace below three lines:

```js
$tbl_row.append($('<td><select class="custom-select" name="section1_' + key + '" id="section1_' + key + '"><option value="">-Select-</option><option value="Y">Enabled</option><option value="N">Disabled</option></select></td>'));
$tbl_row.append($('<td><select class="custom-select" name="section2_' + key + '" id="section2_' + key + '"><option value="">-Select-</option><option value="Y">Enabled</option><option value="N">Disabled</option></select></td>'));
$tbl_row.append($('<td><select class="custom-select" name="section2_' + key + '" id="section3_' + key + '"><option value="">-Select-</option><option value="Y">Enabled</option><option value="N">Disabled</option></select></td>'));

To

$tbl_row.append($('<td><select class="custom-select" name="section1_' + key + '" id="section1_' + key + '"><option value="" '+ (ajax_data[key]['section_1'] == '' ? "selected": "") +'>-Select-</option><option value="Y" '+ (ajax_data[key]['section_1'] == 'Y' ? "selected": "") +'>Enabled</option><option value="N" '+ (ajax_data[key]['section_1'] == 'N' ? "selected": "") +'>Disabled</option></select></td>'));
$tbl_row.append($('<td><select class="custom-select" name="section2_' + key + '" id="section2_' + key + '"><option value="" '+ (ajax_data[key]['section_2'] == '' ? "selected": "") +'>-Select-</option><option value="Y" '+ (ajax_data[key]['section_2'] == 'Y' ? "selected": "") +'>Enabled</option><option value="N" '+ (ajax_data[key]['section_2'] == 'N' ? "selected": "") +'>Disabled</option></select></td>'));
$tbl_row.append($('<td><select class="custom-select" name="section2_' + key + '" id="section3_' + key + '"><option value="" '+ (ajax_data[key]['section_3'] == '' ? "selected": "") +'>-Select-</option><option value="Y" '+ (ajax_data[key]['section_3'] == 'Y' ? "selected": "") +'>Enabled</option><option value="N" '+ (ajax_data[key]['section_3'] == 'N' ? "selected": "") +'>Disabled</option></select></td>'));
```

:

Comment: Is it still any issue with this solution?

Comment: Do you get chance to look into this?